# How to include plotly in R Studio Presentations (Rpres)

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly, htmlwidgets, rpres

How to include a plotly plot in a Rpres file?
If you do it like in a normal Rmd file

````
Basic Plot
========================================================
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)
plot_ly(economics, x = date, y = unemploy / pop)
```
````

The result looks as follows:
[image: Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection]

The solution I came up with, which uses the possibility that Markdown can contain HTML:

````
Basic Plot
========================================================
```{r, results='hide', echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)
p = plot_ly(economics, x = date, y = unemploy / pop)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as.widget(p), file = "demo.html")
```
<iframe src="demo.html" style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>
````

But I am hoping for a somehow more elegant solution which does not use any additional files.

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks. Alternatively, plotly works fine with ioslides rendered from Rmarkdown.

Comment: @Antoine Can you elaborate a bit on this workflow?

Comment: I have added a minimal example on how to do this as an answer below. Let me know if this is not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 6):

The following is a minimal example on how to include a plot_ly graph in an ioslides presentation, so it does not quite answer the question for Rpres, but provides an alternative.

The first slide displays a plot transformed from a ggplot into a plot_ly, preserving the ggplot style.
The second slide displays a plot using plot_ly directly.

````
---
title: "Plot_ly demo"
date: "8 December 2016"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## A simple plot_ly

```{r, fig.align='center', message = FALSE}
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x =  1:10, y = (1:10)^2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + labs(x = "X", y = "Y", title = "X and Y")

ggplotly(p)
```

## Another simple plot_ly

```{r, echo = FALSE, fig.align = 'center', message = FALSE}
plot_ly(df, x = x, y = y)
```
````

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. When I executed `slidify(index.Rmd)`, there was a message saying `PhantomJS not found`, and suggesting me run `webshot::install_phantomjs()`. So I did and the error was gone. However I still got no plotly interactive map output. It was blank.

Also tried the following code in terminal, which worked for some people but not for me. I got html file output, and there still wasn't a map. It comes from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360338/cant-generate-plotly-interactive-plots-in-rmarkdown-report). It might work for you.

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); library(rmarkdown); 
rmarkdown::render('index.Rmd', output_file='index.html')"
```

I am sure it is plotly. Cause ggplots works fine.

**Update:**

Reinstalled/updated the wetshot package by running `install.packages("webshot")`, then ran `webshot::install_phantomjs()` again, then `library(knitr); library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render('index.Rmd', output_file='index.html')`. It worked. The html file has a plotly map, though it doesn't appear in the Knitr preview window.

**Update:**

By adding the following code, I am able to display the map in the sides. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860207/adjust-the-size-of-plotly-charts-in-slidify).

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), "p.html")
cat('<iframe src="./p.html" width=100% height=100% allowtransparency="true"> </iframe>')
```

Full context would be something listed below.

```
library(plotly)
cities <- readRDS("D:/R/data/cn_cities.rds")
cities <- cities[1:50,]

geo <- list(
  scope = 'asia',
  projection = list(type = 'Mercator'),
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("white"),
  subunitcolor = toRGB("white"),
  countrywidth = 1,
  subunitwidth = 1)

p <- plot_geo(cities, 
              locationmode='CHN', 
              sizes=c(1, 200)) %>% 
     add_markers(x=~lng, y=~lat, 
                 size=~sqrt(population),
                 hoverinfo="text", 
                 text=~paste(city, "<br />", population)) %>%
     layout(title='', 
            geo=geo)

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), "p.html")
cat('<iframe src="./p.html" width=100% height=100% allowtransparency="true"> </iframe>')
```