# Can't generate plotly interactive plots in Rmarkdown report

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, plotly, ggplotly

I have an Rmarkdown document with a plot made with plotly and would like to generate an html file. It works when I click on *Knit to HTML* in Rstudio, but not when I run the following on the command line:

```
Rscript -e "require(knitr)" -e "require(markdown)" -e "knit('Untitled.Rmd', out='report.md')" -e "markdownToHTML('report.md', 'report.html')"
```

After this, I have a report.html file which contains the plot generated with plotly, but it is not interactive.
Does anyone know how to make it interactive with the command line?

Thanks

This is the code, btw:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure_ggplot, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ggplot(pressure,aes(temperature,pressure))+geom_point(size=10,color='red')
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
```{r pressure_plotly, echo=FALSE}

g<-ggplot(pressure,aes(temperature,pressure))+geom_point(size=10,color='red')
ggplotly(g)
```
```{r}
sessionInfo()
```
````

Comment: Check [this link](https://plot.ly/r/knitr/#embedding-plotly-graphs-in-rmd-files), you have to use `htmltools::tags$....`for embedding plotly plots

Comment: No, you actually don't. I do get an embedded plotly plot when I knit from inside Rstudio, but not when I do it from the command line. That's the problem. I may have explained myself a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render('untitled.Rmd', output_file='report.html')"
```

Reasoning: knit seems to default to markdown output, and doesn't retain HTMLwidgets in the rendered markdown. Thus, when converting, you end up with missing files (you can see these errors if you remove `echo=FALSE` from the code block openings.

`rmarkdown::render([...])` renders cleanly to HTML, avoiding the issues mentioned above. If you wish to specify the output format, you can do so using the `output_format` argument.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `rmarkdown::render([...])`? More detail please. Thanks!

Comment: What detail do you want?

Comment: Oh sorry, you just meant the function `rmarkdown::render`, I thought you were doing something fancy with square brackets.